# how implement for loop using Timers?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I'm trying to implement for loop using timers. Actualy my intention is to avoid stuck in long running for loop and have smooth behaviour in my program. is this possible ? any references ?

Comment: For long running operations, better have a look at the [Worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) class, which (sort of) spawns an ActionScript thread.

Comment: Timers are resource intense operation, even if one is not running. as mentioned by RIAstar, use Worker, You need to upgrade your sdk/runtime for this though as it is a fairly a new concept.

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstand what you want, you cam Implement Timer : http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

use function start() to start your timer and listen the event TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE.
If you want restart your timer, use reset() and start() again.